# Generar placas de carros de manera aleatoria

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer el siguiente problema

Generar y mostrar 10 números de placas (cadenas) de manera aleatoria, considerando que los números de placa contienen 9 caracteres, de la siguiente manera:

- Los primeros dos caracteres deben ser consonantes.
- El tercer y noveno caracteres deben ser vocales.
- El cuarto y octavo caracteres son ‘-‘.
- Los caracteres quinto, sexto y séptimo deben ser cifras del 0 al 9

Lo trate de hacer así y fracase:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    int i=0,c=0,vr,cr,nr;
    char caracter;
    String matricula="";
    String vocales="AEIOU";
    String consonantes= "BCDFGHJKLMNÑPQRSTVWXYZ";

    Random aleatorio=new Random();

     for (i=0;i<10;i++){

         for(c=0;c<9;c++){

           if(c==1 || c==2){
               do{

                 caracter = (char)(aleatorio.nextInt(91) + 65);}

               while (vocales.indexOf(caracter) >= 0);

               matricula+= caracter;}


           else if(c==3 || c==9){


               do{

                 caracter = (char)(aleatorio.nextInt(91) + 65);}

               while (consonantes.indexOf(caracter) >= 0);

              matricula+=caracter;}

           else if(c==4 || c==8){
               System.out.print("-");}

           else{
               matricula+= aleatorio.nextInt(10);
           }




         }
         System.out.println("La matrícula es: " +matricula);
     }

   }
 }
```

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverFlow en Español!! Podrías incluir que problema concreto estás teniendo?

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Es muy importante que expliques el error o dificultad que estás teniendo con tu implementación, ya que sólo pegar tu código sin más, hace que sea difícil detectar el problema de forma expedita. Puedes leer [mcve] para que tengas una idea. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Intenta divir tu problema en pequeñas funciones para que se te haga mas sencillo desarrollar el problema ademas si ocupas hacer un cambio no sea un dolor de cabeza entender la logica, algo simple es crear una funciones para crear vocales, consonates y numeros y solo llamarlas para construir el tipo de placa que requieres.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(generarPlaca());
        }
    }


    public static String generarPlaca() {

        char placa[] = new char[9];
        placa[0] = generarConsonante();
        placa[1] = generarConsonante();
        placa[2] = generarVocal();
        placa[3] = '-';
        placa[4] = generarNumero();
        placa[5] = generarNumero();
        placa[6] = generarNumero();
        placa[7] = '-';
        placa[8] = generarVocal();

        return String.valueOf(placa);
    }

    public static char generarConsonante() {
        return generarRandomChar("BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ");
    }

    public static char generarVocal() {
        return generarRandomChar("AEIOU");
    }

    public static char generarNumero() {
        return generarRandomChar("0123456789");
    }

    private static char generarRandomChar(String str) {
        char caracteres[] = str.toCharArray();
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * caracteres.length);
        return caracteres[index];
    }
}
```

Salida

```
XME-881-O
LCE-718-E
SPA-045-I
RRU-854-E
YQA-439-U
HKE-994-A
SKO-217-I
TZI-157-O
BYO-987-O
TMI-285-O
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución rapida podría ser esta:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String vocales="AEIOU";
    String consonantes= "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

    Random r = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        String matricula = "";

        int cons_length = consonantes.length();
        int voc_length = vocales.length();

        // primer y segundo caracter:
        matricula += consonantes.charAt(r.nextInt(cons_length));
        matricula += consonantes.charAt(r.nextInt(cons_length));

        // tercer caracter:
        matricula += vocales.charAt(r.nextInt(voc_length));

        // cuarto caracter:
        matricula += '-';

        // quinto, sexto y septimo caracter:
        matricula += r.nextInt(10);
        matricula += r.nextInt(10);
        matricula += r.nextInt(10);

        // octavo caracter:
        matricula += '-';

        // noveno caracter:
        matricula += vocales.charAt(r.nextInt(voc_length));

        System.out.println( i +" . " + matricula);
    }
}
```